# Regex for anything but 'package-info.java' for checkstyle suppression

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle check RegexpHeader which checks for a regular expression in every files in my source. However, I want to suppress the check for all the files except package-info files. The suppression.xml file has the following suppress check:

```
<suppress checks="RegexpHeader" files="^(?!package\.java).*$"/>
```

It seems like the check is suppressed even in package-info files as it does not throw any errors.

Comment: It is for `package.java` not for `package-info.java`....

Answer (score 3):

You just excluded "package.java" files. Try ading the "-info" part.
This would be:

```
^(?!package-info\.java).*$
```